# .NET - need 10 points around an ellipse

Tags: .net, graphics

Simple code fragment below draws an ellipse on a VB.NET panel.  I now need to locate 10 points ON that ellipse, so I can draw small circles along the edge (the final effect will be an elliptical "table" with 10 "seats" around it.

Help filling in the center of my loop below appreciated.

```
    Private Sub Panel1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Paint

    Const OFFSET As Integer = -36

    Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
    Dim r As Rectangle = Panel1.ClientRectangle
    Dim iAng As Integer


    r.Inflate(OFFSET, OFFSET)
    g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, r)

    For i As Integer = 0 To 9
        iAng = i * 36

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If A is the horizontal radius of the ellipse, and B is the vertical radius, then for any given angle R in radians:

X(R) = A * cos(R)

Y(R) = B * sin(R)

So if you take R = 0, 1 * 2pi/10, 2 * 2pi/10....9 * 2pi/10, then you can find ten seats distributed around the ellipse.